# Automatically validate reCAPTCHA

Tags: javascript, recaptcha, server-side

In my site I have two ways to create an account.

In the first one there is reCAPTCHA, and it is verified normally.

In the second one it is not present.
On the server side, the account creation function is the same and has the check on the validity of the reCAPTCHA.

```
const response = await httpRequest(
  'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify',
  {
    method: POST,
    form: { secret: secretKey, response: options.profile.reCaptchaResponse },
  }
);
```

To make the second way work, I set value `options.profile.reCaptchaResponse` to `true`, but now it doesn't seem to work anymore.

How can I get it to automatically evaluate the reCAPTCHA as if the user had accepted it?